# C# check for installed version of .NET Framework and MS Visual C++ Redist

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c++, verify, installed-applications

How can I check if .NET 4.5+ and MS Visual C++ Redist 2013/2015/2017 are installed on the machine that is running my application?

Comment: You [don't have to check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10033128/17034) for the .NET install.  The C++ redist installer is for end-users, if you need all three of them then you need to fix your project.  Simply avoid your user to have to deploy them by copying the runtime DLLs your program needs in the same folder as your main EXE program.

Comment: Deploy runtime files with your app: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35097193/can-i-bundle-the-visual-studio-2015-c-redistributable-dlls-with-my-applicatio

Comment: I don't want to bundle my app with the files. I just want to check if the mentioned above version of .NET Framework and MS Visual C++ Redist are installed.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of application you are talking about. If you have a installer, you can bundle the .Net and Visual C++ installer, and run it upon installing your application.
Those installers are smart enough to skip if existing or newer versions are found on the machine.

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. I just want to check if the mentioned above version of .NET Framework and MS Visual C++ Redist are installed.